# Unable to setup Matillion OAuth with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, matillion

New Matillion user, and my first project is to read in Google Analytics data by using a google account authorized to access GA data from several clients.

I follow the steps from this Matillion documentation: [Google Query Authentication Guide](http://%20https://documentation.matillion.com/docs/2339840)

I have setup the needed client ID and client secret, and I've pasted the redirect URL into the credentials page in the Google console.

From Matillion, I enter the client ID and secret in the OAuth Configuration dialog, and I configure the proxyserver and proxyport under "advanced connection options" as specified in the Matillion documentation.

When I click the Authorization link in the OAuth it opens a new tab to the Google page where I login and allow the access. Once I do this, the redirect seems(?) to kick in and I presented with a browser page with the message "Authorisation complete     Please close this tab". I am not taken back to the tab where Matillion OAuth configuration is still waiting for a response of some type.

Any ideas with this? Additional information: I setup Matillion via the Snowflake Partner Connect console and am still in the free 14-day trial for Matillion.

Comment: Are you sure you need the proxy options? Have you tried without them?

Comment: Schepo your comment was the final piece of the puzzle. Thank you. The documentation should not have been followed, at least in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the OAuth workflow to finish. Any issues from this point forward will be a battle for another day. Here are my findings:

1. First note that I initiated my Matillion install from the Snowflake Partner Connect, which was very straight forward. I was up and running with Matillion in less than a minute.
2. The Matillion version that launched was 1.50.6, which is behind the most current version 1.58.4. I had no idea this would not be the most current version, as I assume the cloud platform might provide new installs with the latest version. I can see reasons why this might not be the case.
3. After several hours ensuring my GCP project, client id, client key, and other settings were correct everywhere, the workflow still would not complete. I opened a support case with Matillion and it was responded to within 2 hours. That is excellent. The first recommendation was to update Matillion to the latest version as it will address an OAuth issue resembling the one I reported. I saw the new version was very recent, and didn't realize I was nowhere near having the latest version.
4. After the update completed, I tried repeating all of the same steps. The only difference now was that the "Authorisation complete" tab closed on its own returning me to the Matillion tab which still sat "Waiting for response from service...".  The version update seemed to show promise but not a solution.
5. A comment Schepo above cleared the final hurdle: I removed the proxyserver and proxyport "Advanced Connection options" from the OAuth configuration, and then tried getting a new authorization link. Matillion froze up and the session was dead. I had to close the browser, open a new incognito window and repeat the steps - without the proxyserver/proxyport connection settings. This time the workflow completed!

The Matillion documentation for Google Query: https://documentation.matillion.com/docs/2339840 should be updated if the Proxy Settings are not required for all OAuth configurations. The OAuth issue I reported should also be documented somewhere as a known issue addressable by the latest version (if not already).

Answer (score 0):

OAuth being one of the many ways you can set up connectivity with Snowflake; it appears you're attempting to set up External OAuth, that is Google is the authorizing server. My understanding is that there are two paths to setting up OAuth,

This link has the Azure AD setup with the two options, https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Create-External-OAuth-Token-Using-Azure-AD-For-The-OAuth-Client-Itself

Googling to setup Google AD returns https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en

You may have to follow a similar process, follow this content here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-ext-custom.html